# jquery date picker how to colorise data range?

Tags: jquery, css, calendar, background-color, datapicker

For now to set diferent color for one date range 
5. april - 7 april
I use this http://jsfiddle.net/sickworm/dpvz52tf/

```
var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('04/05/2015')] = new Date('04/05/2015');
    SelectedDates[new Date('04/06/2015')] = new Date('05/06/2015');
    SelectedDates[new Date('04/07/2015')] = new Date('04/07/2015');
```

Don't know how to make in one line to to set data range in diferent color from date - to date? For now I need write line for each day in data range... 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this?
 http://jsfiddle.net/sickworm/dpvz52tf/

```
var date1 = new Date('05/09/2015');

    var date2 = new Date('05/11/2015');
```

and

```
return [date.getDay() < 7, date >= date1 && date <= date2 ? "Highlighted" : ""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this example here:
http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview
Open "Forms" from left, then open "Advanced Elements". You'll see there great time and date pickers.
You can download it here:
http://almsaeedstudio.com/
And use the datepicker codes inside. Personally, I'm using them and it is great.